# Mobx State Manager - calling an action from another action causing error

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm implementing a React Todo List with Mobx-State-Tree as a state manager.

from the **fetchTodos** function I'm calling the **setTodos** function.
It seems like the code is working,

but I don't understand why it shows me the following error:

[image]

```
export const TodosStore = types
  .model("TodoStore", {
    todos: types.array(TodoModel)
}).actions(store => ({
    setTodos(newTodos) {
        store.todos = newTodos;
    },
    async fetchTodos() {
        const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}todos`);
        const data = await response.json();

        const newTodos = data.map(todo => ({
            id: todo.id,
            title: todo.title,
            description: todo.description ? todo.description : ""
        }))
        store.setTodos(newTodos);
    },
}));
```

Comment: Please don't post code as images, just copy-paste it as text, so others can use that code too and without typing it manually.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code snippet.

Comment: It's just a TS error, from what I recall there are some few issues with TS support. You can either use @Danila suggestion which is a little bit ugly IMO, or just call it this way: `this.setTodos(newTodos);`

Answer (score 0):

At that stage `setTodos` is not yet bound to the current instance, because both `setTodos` and `fetchTodos` are in the same closure. So you need to declare them as separate functions and then return an object containing this functions, like that:

```
    .actions(self => {
        const setTodos = () => {
            // ...
        }

        const fetchTodos = async => {
            // ...
            // here you can use setTodos now
        } 

        return {
            setTodos,
            fetchTodos
        }
    })
```